# Filter a list of words using Json File

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

My Json File:

```
{
  "countries": [
  "Australia", "France", "Belgium"
  ]
}
```

I have a `index_list = ['Germany', 'USA, 'Ireland, Australia, "France", Belgium, "Kenya", "Spain"`
I want to filter out all the countries which are on the json file.

```
data_json= json.dumps(data["countries"])
res = filter(lambda i: i not in data_json, index_list)
print(res)
```

This gives me `<filter object at 0x0000022D05C0E6A0>` error.

Comment: try `''.join(filter(lambda i: i not in data_json, index_list))`. This is because `filter()` creates a filter object and then you have to convert it to whatever type you want to use it for, like `str` or `list` or so on and it is not an error but a filter object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just cast your JSON data to list() and filter your other data using list comprehension.

```
import json

data_json = list(json.load(open('file.json'))['countries'])

index_list = ['Germany', 'USA', 'Ireland', 'Australia', "France", 'Belgium', "Kenya", "Spain"]

answer = [country for country in index_list if country not in data_json]
print(answer)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of filter you can loop through all elements and check if they exist in list from json

```
import json

data = {"countries": ["Australia", "France", "Belgium"]}

index_list = ["Germany", "USA", "Ireland", "Australia", "France", "Belgium", "Kenya", "Spain"]

data_json= json.dumps(data["countries"]) 
res = [item for item in index_list if item not in data_json] 
print(res)
```

Result: `['Germany', 'USA', 'Ireland', 'Kenya', 'Spain']`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach with the pandas Index.  We don't need a loop (or list comprehension) because the Index includes a `difference()` method.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"countries": ["Australia", "France", "Belgium"]}
index_list = ["Germany", "USA", "Ireland", "Australia", "France", 
              "Belgium", "Kenya", "Spain"]

result = pd.Index(index_list).difference(data['countries']).to_list()
print(result)

['Germany', 'Ireland', 'Kenya', 'Spain', 'USA']
```